# Always get redirected

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.3

Using symfony2.3.4.

I always get redirected with the following security.yml and routing.yml, when I type in the address field: `www.example.com/` or `www.example.com/unsecured/start` or `www.example.com/getlocale` I don't know why. Is there any setting with access_controls wrong? Or is it security: false/true?

Following security.yml:

```
firewalls:
dev:
    pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
    security: false

login:
    pattern:  ^/(en|de)/login
    security: false

secured_area:
    pattern:    ^/
    #anonymous: ~
    http_basic:
        realm: "Secured Area"
    form_login:
        check_path: frontend_account_security_check
        login_path: frontend_account_login
        use_referer:        true
        #default_target_path: frontend_account_my_account
        #target_path_parameter: frontend_account_my_account
    logout: 
        path:   /en/secured/logout
        target: /getlocale
        #anonymous: ~
    #http_basic:
    #    realm: "Secured Demo Area"

access_control:
- { path: ^/en/unsecured/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
- { path: ^/de/unsecured/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
- { path: ^/en/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
- { path: ^/de/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
- { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

My routing.yml:

```
frontend_account_login:
  pattern:  /{_locale}/login
  defaults: { _controller: FrontendAccountBundle:Secured:login }
  requirements:
    _locale: en|de

frontend_main_index:
  pattern:  /
  defaults: { _controller: FrontendMainBundle:Main:index }

frontend_main_getlocale:
  pattern:  /getlocale
  defaults: { _controller: FrontendMainBundle:Main:getlocale }

frontend_main_inlocale:
  pattern: /unsecured/start
  defaults: { _controller: FrontendMainBundle:Main:start }
```

Comment: I think it has to do with "pattern:    ^/" in your "secured_area:" settings?

Comment: I think so too, but how can I change it? I want to get to the security context in an PHP(!) template. In a twig template it is very easy. I always read that you need to set up your firewall correct. Any idea?

Comment: I got it, if you are interested, take a look at my answer. Thanks for watching and partcipating.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, crap, I missed a very little thing. The correct answer is:

```
secured_area:
pattern:    ^/
anonymous: ~    //activate the anonymous

access_control:
- { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
- { path: ^/de/secured/, roles: ROLES_USER }
```